# HTMl de uma página não retorna nenhum valor

Tags: r, rvest

Estou tentanto raspar os dados de uma página e estou usando o seguinte código

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)

link <- "https://sig.tse.jus.br/ords/dwapr/r/seai/sig-candidaturas/lista-candidatos?session=203181203884221"

pagina <- read_html(link)

links_candidatos <- pagina %>% 
  html_nodes(".t-Report-cell a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

Essa primeira parte me retorna os valores corretamente. Consigo capturar os links que quero. Porém quando tento ler os atributos internos aos links com:

```
captar_dados <- function(links_candidatos){
  socio <- read_html(links_candidatos)
  dados <- socio %>% 
    html_nodes(".col-md-4.ng-scope:nth-child(1) h3") %>% 
    html_text()
}
```

Me retorna apenas NAs. Já utilizei todos os argumentos HTML possível mas parece que a página não libera os valores. Alguém sabe como lidar com esse problema?

Comment: Não sei se esse atributo é localizado, mas há diversas coisas para observar, sua função não retornaria o resultado, o parâmetro da função seria melhor entendido se fosse `link` não `links_candidatos`. Esses dados estão disponíveis no TSE, não seria melhor baixar?